# 3D plot in R using persp3D - Axis issues

Tags: r, matrix, 3d, rgl

I have a matrix (m) and I'm trying to plot a 3D representation of that matrix.

```
    > dput(head(m))

structure(c(21930, 21844, 21758, 21672, 21586, 21500, 22016, 
21930, 21844, 21758, 21672, 21586, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 26L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("freq.min", "freq.max", "X0", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", 
    "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13", 
    "X14", "X15", "X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", "X20", "X21", "X22", 
    "X23")))
```

I managed to plot a 3D surface plot, but both the axes and the axis labels are incorrect. Note that the 3D surface plot below uses the entire matrix rather than just the header, which I only include here as the dput for brevity.

```
persp3D(z = m[,3:26], col = "lightgrey", shade = 0.5, ticktype = "detailed", axes=T)
```

[image]

Let's start with the axes themselves: the axis that goes from X0 to X23 should be the X axis of the matrix (column names), but here it is regarded as the Y axis. The Y axis, regarded here as the X axis, ranges from 0 to 22016 in 256 intervals of 86.

I've spent the last many hours scouring the internet for answers on how to change the axis labels, but have not succeeded. From what I understand, if I turn off the axis argument in persp3D (axes=F) I can then customize the axis in a subsequent line, like so:

```
axis3d(edge= 'y+-', at =seq(0,23,by=1) ,
       labels = seq(0,23,by=1))
```

However, a RGL device pops up, and only the axis is plotted without the actual plot itself, which stays unchanged in the built-in R graphics device.

How do I successfully change the axes?

Comment: Where does your y-value come ? Is it written in your matrix ?  (`freq.min` and `freq.max` are larger than 21586). 1th row is 0 and 2nd row is 86 ? (but `21586/86` is 251)

Comment: @dww, thank you for the suggestion--I will keep that in mind for the future so as to avoid coming off as crass.

Comment: @cuttlefish44, my y value corresponds to the 256 rows. I had mistyped--thanks for catching that. The top row has a freq.max of 22016, which, divided by the 86-width intervals, is 256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this what you're looking for?

```
clab <- 0:23
rlab <- seq(0, 21586, 86)

cnum <- length(clab)
rnum <- length(rlab)

m <- matrix(
  c(runif(0.5*cnum*rnum)-1, runif(0.5*cnum*rnum)+1), 
  rnum, cnum, 
  dimnames = list(rlab, clab))

library(rgl)

plot3d(
  clab, rlab, t(m),
  type="n",
  aspect = c(100, 200, 20),
  xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z",
  sub = "Grab me and rotate me!"
)

surface3d(
  clab, rlab, t(m),
  color = c("black", "white"),
  alpha = 0.5,
  add = TRUE
)
```

To change the axis you can interchange x and y and transpose z with `t()`.

As a side note: I wrote two functions to transform 3D point cloud data from tall to wide format and vice versa: `recexcavAAR::spatialwide` and `recexcavAAR::spatiallong`. I find them quite useful to go back and forth between plotting and analysis. Maybe they're useful for you.

**Edit:**
Alternative solution with single call to persp3d

```
clab <- 0:23
rlab <- seq(0, 21586, 86)

cnum <- length(clab)
rnum <- length(rlab)

m <- matrix(
  c(runif(0.5*cnum*rnum)-1, runif(0.5*cnum*rnum)+1), 
  rnum, cnum, 
  dimnames = list(rlab, clab))

library(rgl)

persp3d(
  clab, rlab, t(m),
  color = c("black", "white"),
  alpha = 0.5,
  aspect = c(100, 200, 20),
  xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z",
  sub = "Grab me and rotate me!"
)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I was really hoping to use the persp3D function, as it allows me to directly print several surface plots on a graphics device in a standard manner. How might I adapt this code for the persp3d function?

Comment: Or, on another thought @nevrome, can you suggest a way to print several plots together by defining par(mfrow=c(3,1) using the plot3d and surface3d functions?

Comment: persp3d and surface3d are interchangeable in this context. My code yields the same result if you replace surface3d with persp3d. I'm not sure if you can display different 3D Plots in the same rgl window. But you sure can display many surfaces at once. Maybe [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recexcavAAR/vignettes/recexcavAAR-vignette-1.html) example helps you.

Comment: Terrific--that works great! I just accepted your answer. Thank you.

Comment: You can put multiple plots in a single window.  See `?mfrow3d`.